# Does Ruby on Rails support document relative paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-2

As far as I can tell url helpers in Ruby on Rails only generate **site root relative paths**.

So if I want to go from `http://exemple.com/categories/1` to `http://exemple.com/questions/12`  the link  will be `/questions/12` (site root relative path).

Are there any helpers/gems that would generate a **[document relative path](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html)** (`../questions/12`) ?

Comment: did you try to put you documents in rails `public` folder and then access it like railsapp --> public--->folder1---->folder2---->my.html   now access it http://localhost/folder1/folder2/my.html ...hope i am able to understand

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the question.

Assuming you have the two following routes:

```
resources :categories
resources :questions
```

You can jump from one to the other using:

```
category_path(id)
question_path(id)
```

Using the suffix `path` will only return the relative path for your domain. Whereas using `url` will return the full URL.

```
category_path(1) #=> /categories/1
category_url(1)  #=> http://exemple.com/categories/1
```

Comment: Hi Pierre-Louis, I'm well aware of this behaviour. the category_path returns a site root relative path. I'm looking for a way to generate document relative paths.

Comment: I've added a link in the question that explains the difference between document relative paths and site root relative paths.

Comment: Ok I get it, the only way I see to perform such thing would be to add manually the `../` :( Let's wait if someone comes with a clever thing.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois did he asking about documents in rails public folder and then access it like railsapp --> public--->folder1---->folder2---->my.html now access it http://localhost:3000/folder1/folder2/my.html ...hope i am able to understand

Comment: @Rajarshi Das This is not the question

Comment: ooh got it....... but in rails route there is no such option  you have to do it manually `match "../", ""`